# Как что-то записать в список используя метод (функцию) open()

Tags: python, telebot

Я не гений но пишу код на 400+ строк кода для тг бота.
Все было нормально пока я не осознал что надо добавить функцию регистрации пользователя.

И все вроде бы окей если бы не одна проблема, при записи с помощью метода open(users.py, 'a+') он записывает юзеров и пароль в конце файла а использовать open(users.py, 'w') не могу т.к. он стирает прошлые записи в фале тоже самое и c client.py (он нужен чтобы узнать вошел ли пользователь или нет если нет то он не получает доступ)

вот урезанный main.py

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
from pyqiwip2p.types import QiwiCustomer, QiwiDatetime
import random
from settings import token as tk
import datetime
import users
import client

bot = telebot.TeleBot(tk.telebot)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_messages(message):

    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
    rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton ('Войти'),types.KeyboardButton ('Создать'))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Войдите или зарегистрируйтесь " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' !',reply_markup = rmk)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reg_users)
    

def reg_users(message):
    if message.text == 'Войти':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите пароль " + str(message.from_user.username))
        l = str(message.from_user.username)
        print (l)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, l_users)
    
    if message.text == 'Создать':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Создайте пороль, а логин ваш будет : " + str(message.from_user.username) + '')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, r_users)


def l_users(message):
    p = str(message.text)
    e = True
    while e:
        l = str(message.from_user.username)
        print(l)
        if l in users.users:
            e = False
            if p == users.users[l]:
                s = open('client.py', 'a+')
                s.write(" '"+ l +"', " )
                s.close()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Вы вошли в аккаунт " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' Вот список всех комманд: бла бла бла ' )
                break
            else:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"пороль не верен ! " + str(message.from_user.username)+ ' Повторите попытку /register')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, l_users)
                break

def r_users (message):
    l = str(message.from_user.username)
    p = str(message.text)
    s = open('users.py', 'a+')
    s.write('\n    "'+ l + '" : "' + str(p) + '",' )
    s.close()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш аккаунт создан войдите в него /register . Ваш логин : " + str(message.from_user.username))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,reg_users)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

вот что находится в users.py (я в него сам добавил себя что бы проверить работоспособность)

```
users = {
    "Adammuesly" : "1234",

}
```

вот users.py (без моего вмешательство)

```
users = {     

    } "Adammuesly" : "1234",
```

точно также как и в users.py записывается в client.py

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение, что вам необходимо поменять подход к данной задаче. Могу порекомендовать следующие варианты:

1. Использовать базу данных, хотя бы [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)
2. Использовать json файл, а не `.py`
3. А если все-таки будете использовать вашу логику, то при небольшом количестве данных можно организовать вот так: чтение всей информации из файла -> обновление нужных строк/записей -> полная перезапись файла. Здесь я не хочу писать данную реализацию, так как это костыль.

Логика для json файла примерно такая же, но она позволяет не использовать строковые переменные и методы поиска и вставки, а использовать более удобные методы словаря

```py
import json

def add_to_file(user, password):
    with open("users.json") as f:
        initial = json.load(f)
    initial[user] = password
    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(initial, f)
```

а для того, чтобы обратиться с словарю, который хранится в json

```py
def check_user(user):
    with open("users.json") as f:
        data_from_file = json.load(f)
    if user in data_from_file :
        print(f"Да, {user} существует")
        return True
    else:
        print(f"Нет такого {user}")
        return False
```

Небольшие тесты:
Изначальный `users.json`

```json
{
    "Adammuesly": "1234"
}
```

Добавим пару пользователей

```py
add_to_file("user", "pass")
add_to_file("user1", "pass")
```

Проверяем `users.json`

```json
{
    "Adammuesly": "1234",
    "user": "pass",
    "user1": "pass"
}
```

Проверим пользователей:

```py
user_for_check = ["Adammuesly", "user", "USER"]
for user in user_for_check:
    check_user(user)
```

Вывод

```py
Да, Adammuesly существует
Да, user существует
Нет такого USER
```

Comment: вы хоть раз пользовались pytelebotapi ? мне надо записать в отдельный файл имя пользователя( из тг) а если использовать как вы json то там триллион ошибок выйдет. Мне надо автоматизировать все sqlite просто не удобный

Comment: нет не пользовался, но это не значит, что я должен использовать только те интерфейсы, что мне предлагаются из коробки, это раз. Вам не кажется `import users` проблемой? после изменения в `users.py`, будут ли видны новые пользователи? это два. Ну, и третье, костыли - это наша обыденность

Comment: понял простите если задел, но ошибки делают нас сильнее

Comment: @Adammuesly да, ну, бросьте) нас тяжело задеть.

Answer (score 0):

Короче я наверное решил одну проблему с client.py теперь он делает все как я хочу

main.py урезанный но исправленный

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import time
from pyqiwip2p import QiwiP2P
from pyqiwip2p.types import QiwiCustomer, QiwiDatetime
import random
from settings import token as tk
import datetime
import users
import client

bot = telebot.TeleBot(tk.telebot)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_messages(message):

    rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
    rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton ('Войти'),types.KeyboardButton ('Создать'))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Войдите или зарегистрируйтесь " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' !',reply_markup = rmk)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, reg_users)
    

def reg_users(message):
    if message.text == 'Войти':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите пароль " + str(message.from_user.username))
        l = str(message.from_user.username)
        print (l)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, l_users)
    
    if message.text == 'Создать':
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Создайте пороль, а логин ваш будет : " + str(message.from_user.username) + '')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, r_users)


def l_users(message):
    p = str(message.text)
    e = True
    while e:
        l = str(message.from_user.username)
        print(l)
        if l in users.users:
            e = False
            if p == users.users[l]:
                Client = client.a
                Client.append(str(l))
                s = open('client.py', 'w')
                s.write('a = ' + str(Client))
                s.close()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Вы вошли в аккаунт " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' Вот список всех комманд: бла бла бла ' )
                break
            else:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"пороль не верен ! " + str(message.from_user.username)+ ' Повторите попытку /register')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, l_users)
                break

def r_users (message):
    l = str(message.from_user.username)
    p = str(message.text)
    s = open('users.py', 'a+')
    s.write('\n    "'+ l + '" : "' + str(p) + '",' )
    s.close()
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ваш аккаунт создан войдите в него /register . Ваш логин : " + str(message.from_user.username))
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,reg_users)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

вот исправленная функция его практическое применение в   `def l_users(message):`

```
def l_users(message):
    p = str(message.text)
    e = True
    while e:
        l = str(message.from_user.username)
        print(l)
        if l in users.users:
            e = False
            if p == users.users[l]:
                Client = client.a
                Client.append(str(l))
                s = open('client.py', 'w')
                s.write('a = ' + str(Client))
                s.close()
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Вы вошли в аккаунт " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' Вот список всех комманд: бла бла бла ' )
                break
            else:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"пороль не верен ! " + str(message.from_user.username)+ ' Повторите попытку /register')
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, l_users)
                brea
```

теперь эта функция после того как пользователь создал или вошел в свой акк
добавляет его имя в список и копирует все то что там было и добавляет нового пользователя в конце. Да да это гениально я сам в шоке

Вот его практическое применение в тг
после вызова функции /balance бот ищет имя пользователя списке client.py, если он там есть то он дает доступ ко всем функциям бота, а если нет то говорит ему создать акк или войти в него :)

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['balance'])
def balance(message):
    clients = str(client.a)
    l = str(message.from_user.username)
    if l in clients:
        print('такой пользователь ' + l + 'есть')       
        e = True
        while e:  
            print(l)
            if l in users.users:
                e = False
                rmk = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True,one_time_keyboard=True)
                rmk.add(types.KeyboardButton ('Да'))
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Хотите увидть ваш баланс " + str(message.from_user.username) + ' ?',reply_markup = rmk)
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_balance)
                break
            else:
                msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Ты как зашел суда, сначала надо войти нажми на /register " + str(message.from_user.username) )
                bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, start_messages)
                break
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'такого пользователя ' + l + ' нет, войдите в аккаунт или создайте его нажав на /start ' )
```